# How create a spring roo addon?

Tags: maven-2, spring-roo

I try to create a spring addon for web mvc language support.
And I fellow this instructions:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-springroo3/

After roo created the files,I import them to eclipse.
I found the pom.xml with a warning"Missing artifact org.framework.roo;org.sringframework.roo.process.manager "

I find HindiLanguage.java  can`t find these file:
import org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.jsp.i18n.AbstractLanguage;
import org.springframework.roo.support.util.FileUtils;

But these files is the Spring Roo`s basic files.

So how can I correct is?

Answer (score 0):

Check your pom.xml for missing Roo dependencies, it seems Roo jars aren't resolved.

Another useful guide is http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/simple-addons.html